# laravel Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image_likes.gallery_image_id'

Tags: php, laravel

i'm getting the following error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image_likes.gallery_image_id'
>   in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `image_likes` where
>   `image_likes`.`gallery_image_id` in (1) and `deleted_at` is null and
>   `user_id` = 1 and `image_likes`.`deleted_at` is null)

whenever i add the `function ($query)`.

the line of code below gets the data, but i need the data to get the likes that corresponds with it.

`$images = GalleryImage::with('user')->get()`

this is what i have so far.

**ImageLike.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\GalleryImage;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ImageLike extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'image_id'
    ];

}
```

**ImageController.php**

```
public function getImages()
{

    $images = GalleryImage::with('user')
                        ->with(['likes' => function ($query) {
                                    $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                                    $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);

                        }])->get(); 


    return response()->json($images); 
}
```

**GalleryImage.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;
use App\GalleryImage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class GalleryImage extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'image_title',
        'user_id',
        'file_name', 
        'created_at'
    ];

    protected $table = 'images';


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {
         return $this->hasMany(ImageLike::class);
    }

    public function likedByMe()
    {
        foreach($this->likes as $like) {
            if ($like->user_id == auth()->id()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of  "Select * from image_likes limit 1;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your relationship in model GalleryImage for `likes`

```
public function likes()
{
   return $this->hasMany(ImageLike::class, 'image_id'); //here image_id is reference id of images table to likes table
}
```

default laravel assume your model name and _id as foreign key so it was looking for `gallery_image_id` for your GalleryImage model in `ImageLike` model but you have `image_id`. So if you have other than default then specific it in relationship.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

check details here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: @ Troll owl .. because Laravel by default takes foregin key on model relation .. you may refer doc for more : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 1):

```
public function likedByMe()
{
    return $this->likes()->whereUserId(auth()->id)->count()>0;
}
```

this is not regarding you problem but, you can re-write your `likedByMe()` like this in more efficient way